# Assign value to powershell variable within Jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I came across several documents on how to run a Powershell script within Jenkins pipeline and how to capture output.
However I want to use the captured output for next node powershell script.
e.g.

```
node {
    def msg = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'Write-Output "PowerShell is mighty!"')
}
```

Now I want to use `msg` in the next node within Powershell script. Like if we can assign it to a powershell variable and then perform operations with that variable.
Any pointers on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the powershell output to an environment variable and use that in the subsequent nodes:

```
node {
    env.msg = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'Write-Output "PowerShell is mighty!"')
}

node {
    def output = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '''
        $message = ($env:msg).trim()
        Write-Output $message
    ''')
    println(output)
}
```

Notice the **env** prefix before variable `msg`. You can retrieve the variable within powershell in next node using `$env:` prefix followed by variable name. Don't forget to trim the variable (`.trim()`) within powershell to remove newline.